How do I add HTML column elements to a dynamic table with VB.NET
I want to create a dynamic table with a fixed layout (css table-layout:fixed). Because the first row of my table contains cells with colspan, I cannot specify all column widths that way, so I guess I need to add HTML column elements (col tags) to specify the width of each column. When I try to do this with literal controls, I get the error:
'Table' cannot have children of type 'LiteralControl'.
Here is my code:
Private Function createTable() As Table
    Dim tbl As New Table, myLt As LiteralControl
    myLt=New LiteralControl("<col width=""40"" />") 
    tbl.Controls.Add(myLt)                  
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim tr As TableRow = New TableRow()
        For j As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim tc As TableCell = New TableCell()
            myLt = New LiteralControl("Cell:" & i & "," & j)
            tc.Controls.Add(myLt)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        Next j
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next i
    Return tbl
End Function

So my question is: is it possible to add HTML column elements to a dynamic table with VB.NET?

Is this windows forms? Or what UI framework is this using?

I want to use it for ASP.NET Web Forms, to add a custom header to a GridView control.
